# Convergence of the $p$-norm of $f+f(x-h)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis

I'm reading a book in harmonic analysis, and there is one step in a proof that the author thought should be trivial:

Suppose $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$, $p\geq1$, then $\lim_{h\to \infty} \| f+f(x-h)\|_{p}=2^{\frac{1}{p}}\|f\|_{p}$.

I have never seen this before, neither can I show it's correct. Could someone give some help?

Comment: A possible idea: Let $g$ be continuous, compactly supported and $\|f-g\|_p < \epsilon$, then $\|g - g(\;\cdot\; - h)\|_p^p = 2 \|g\|_p^p$ for $|h|$ sufficiently large.

Comment: @user251257 Using this, I can only prove that LHS is equal or smaller than RHS, the reverse is not obvious.

Comment: why? We have $| \|f\|_p - \|g\|_p | \le \|f-g\|_p < \epsilon$. Let $\epsilon\to 0$.

Comment: In fact, you can replace $g$ by $f\cdot 1_{[-n, n]}$ and let $n\to infty$.

Comment: It is not true for $p=\infty$, just take $f=1$.

Comment: @user251257 That’s indeed obvious, thanks!

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, you are right.

Comment: My attempts have failed unless I take $p=1$ or assume that $f$ has bounded support.

Comment: @copper.hat you can approximate $f$ with functions of bounded support.

Comment: @user251257: It is straightforward if $f$ has bounded support, but you need to switch the limit over $h$ with the approximations and that is not clear.

Comment: @copper.hat for a function with bounded support you don't need a limit. it isn't really a double limit. So it is pretty straight forward.

Comment: @user251257: Well, it is not to me. Go ahead and add an answer. (I am assuming $p < \infty$, of course.)

Comment: @copper.hat done

Comment: @copper.hat I select a $n$ only. It doesn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by @copper.hat the statement is wrong for $p=\infty$.

**Proof for $p\in[1,\infty)$:**

For convenience, I will drop the $p$ in $\|\,\cdot\,\|_p$ and denote $ g(\,\cdot\, - h)$ by $\tau_h g$.

Let $f_n = f\cdot 1_{[-n, n]}$. Notice that $f_n\to f$ in $p$-norm by dominated convergence theorem.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, there exists some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\|f - f_n\| < \epsilon$. Now, for every $h > h_0 := 2n$ we have
$$ \| f_n - \tau_h f_n \| = 2^{1/p} \|f_n\|, $$
as their supports are disjoint.
Further, by the reversed triangle inequality and substitution, we have
$$ |\| f - \tau_h f \| - \|f_n - \tau_h f_n\|| \le \| f- \tau_h f - f_n + \tau_h f_n \| \le \| f - f_n\| + \underbrace{\|\tau_h f - \tau_h f_n \|}_{=\|f - f_n\|} \le 2\epsilon $$
In particular, we have
$$ \begin{align*}  
|\| f - \tau_h f \| - 2^{1/p} \| f\||
&\le \underbrace{|\| f - \tau_h f \| - \|f_n - \tau_h f_n\||}_{\le 2\epsilon} \\ 
&+ \underbrace{|\|f_n - \tau_h f_n\| - 2^{1/p} \|f_n\||}_{=0} \\
&+ \underbrace{|2^{1/p} \|f_n\| - 2^{1/p} \| f\||}_{\le 2^{1/p}\epsilon}.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: How do you get $|\| f - \tau_h f \| - \|f_n - \tau_h f_n\|| < 2 \epsilon$?

Comment: @copper.hat I have extended the answer.